# In R, how can I filter a data frame by data type using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am still learning R and would really appreciate it if someone could show me a simple way to filter a data frame by data type (i.e. only factors) using dplyr so that the output is just a list of variables of the chosen data type?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

As it was kindly pointed out, I am missing an example (first post, sorry!). I am trying to do something like the following:

```
df %>%
  filter(typeof(.) == "integer") %>%
  names()
```

The above just returns all of the variables in my data frame, not just those of type integer which is what I would like. I would like to be able to filter for other data types as well, not just integers :)

Comment: I don't know if that would help you, but here you can see by column type: https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/09/29/r-filtering-data-frames-by-column-type-x-must-be-numeric/

Comment: Presumably something along the lines of `%>% select( is.factor(.) )` but you have not done your reading of the SO "manual" and your question has no [MCVE]

Comment: Are you only after factors, or did you want a solution which works for any given data type? You've said _i.e. only factors_ but I suspect you mean _e.g. only factors_?

Comment: Sorry, it's my first SO post - I'll edit the question accordingly! And Mike you are right, I am looking for a solution that could be used/altered slightly for any data type :)

Comment: `Filter` gets you rows, `select` columns. In each column, you will only have data of one class - this means no matter by what class you `filter`, you will always get all rows or none.

Comment: @Tjebo thank you for the clarification on using `select` and `filter`, indeed, this is likely why I was having trouble!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do like this (package agnostic) using base R:

```
get_names = names(df)[sapply(df, is.factor)]
df = df[,get_names]
```

In `dplyr`, you can do:

```
df <- df %>% 
    select_if(is.factor)
```

Comment: Hi YOLO, thank you for your answer! Unless somebody provides an answer using dplyr (which would be most helpful to me), then I will mark your answer as correct since it also does what I was looking for! :)

Comment: @Sean added to answer.

Comment: I am confused. The OP asked for `filter`, but this is `select` ...? I guess select is what the OP wanted from the very start...

Comment: Sorry for confusing you @Tjebo, as I said, this was my first post so still getting to grips with SO way of things! Even though YOLO's answer has used `select_if` their answer has still filtered (as in to "process or assess (items) in order to reject those that are unwanted") by data type, which is what I was looking for. I will, however, be sure to word my future questions more carefully :)

Comment: @Sean haha no worries, this was German humour trying to point out a mixed up terminology (as pointed out in my comment above, to your question)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @YOLO's answer, you can have it all in one line like this

```
df = df[,sapply(df, is.factor, simplify = TRUE)]
```